# Change namespace with conditional compilation attribute in bulk

Tags: c#, regex

Suppose we have an existing code as;

```
namespace Company.Product1
{
    class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

Now we need to change the namespace based on conditional symbol so that it becomes;

```
#if PRODUCT1
namespace Company.Product1
#else
namespace Company.Product2
#endif
{
    class Class1
    {

    }
}
```

Since we have hundreds of classes, it will take a lot of time doing manually. Is there any simple way? Or how can I do this using regex?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally compiling entire namespaces - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589867/conditionally-compiling-entire-namespaces-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like an anti-pattern to have the same code in two different namespaces but you may have some reasons that I am not aware of so I will try to answer you question anyway. Also, note that a tool like Resharper makes it easy to rename an entire namespace using the refactor tool.

To simply replace the namespace definition in each source file you can use the Visual Studio 2013 text editor (should also work in previous versions):

1) Select **Edit** > **Find and Replace** > **Quick Replace**

2) In the **Search term** text box enter the text **namespace Company.Product1**

3) In the **Replacement term** text box enter the text **#if PRODUCT1\nnamespace Company.Product1\n#else\nnamespace Company.Product2\n#endif**. Notice how newlines are entered using **\n**.

4) Make sure that **Use Regular Expressions** is checked. This is the option that allows you to have escaped newlines in the replacement text. You can also check **Match case** and **Match whole word**.

5) Set the scope to **Entire Solution**.

6) Click on **Replace all** to make the replacement.

Comment: "It seems like an anti-pattern to have the same code in two different namespaces but you may have some reasons that I am not aware of so I will try to answer you question anyway." Thanks for that attitude. Not everyone posting to SO has control over the greater technical environment they work in.